# Python (Pytorch) loss function syntax

Tags: loss-function, pytorch

I have seen many examples of this syntax that is being used for the loss function specifically:

loss = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()(pred, y)

Can anyone explain me what does the (pred, y) do exactly, that it directly computes the loss, instead of calling loss as a function of these 2 arguments again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of Python's builtin `__call__` method, as described [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__call__-in-python/). In short: BCEWithLogitsLoss is a *class*. The first set of parentheses (empty, in your case) provides any needed arguments to the class initializer. Then the second set of parentheses are passed to the call method. So, this is convenient syntax that allows you to instantiate the class and evaluate one of its methods in one line.

Confirming this in the source code is actually a bit difficult. You can see the source for BCEWithLogitsLoss [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/loss.html#BCEWithLogitsLoss), which confirms it is a class. But its only method is `forward`; where is `__call__`? For that, we notice that the BCEWithLogitsLoss class inherits from the `_WeightedLoss` class, which inherits from `Loss`, which inherits from `Module`. We can then see that this base class [implements](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L471) the mapping between `__call__` and `forward`.